# trying to post $_SESSION['username] in database table

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I am close to finishing a class project. I have to create a calorie tracking website. I already coded the login forms and php files. Take into account that I somehow semi-learned to code in php in a couple days, so I'm no expert. Here is the login.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    session_start();
    include("config.php"); //including config.php in our file

    $username = $_POST['Username']; //Storing username in $username variable.
    $password = $_POST['Password']; //Storing password in $password variable.


    $match = "SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."';"; 

    $qry = mysql_query($match);

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry); 

    if ($num_rows <= 0) 
    { 

        echo "Sorry, either the username or the password are incorrect. ";

        echo "Try again";



        exit; 

    } else {

        $_SESSION['username']= $_POST['username'];
        //echo $_SESSION['username'];
        header('Location:profile/index.html');
        // It is the page where you want to redirect user after login.
    }
} ?>
```

After the user logs in, he is taken to a page where he inputs his workout information, and i want to store all of that information in a table. here is the php that will handle that, input.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

define('DB_NAME', 'ritetrak');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Buddy3942');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$_SESSION['username']= $_POST['username'];
//$value= $_SESSION['username'];
$value2= $_POST['WorkoutType'];
$value3 = $_POST['Weight'];
$value4 = $_POST['HeartRate'];
$value5 = $_POST['Calories'];
$value6 = $_POST['TimeSpent'];
$value7 = $_POST['DayOfWeek'];
$value8= $_POST['Mood'];


$sql = "
    INSERT INTO demographics (
        Username, WorkoutType, Weight, HeartRate, Calories,
        TimeSpent, DayOfWeek, Mood) 
    VALUES (
        '$_SESSION['username']', '$value2', '$value3',
        '$value4', '$value5', '$value6', '$value7', '$value8'
    )
";





if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();

header('Location: yourmain/index.html'); ?>
```

I can get everything to store in my 'demographics' table in my database, except the current username that is logged in. and I already searched thru some other questions here and could not find anything. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You need to start the session only once. Remove second `session_start` from `login.php`.

Comment: Start by removing the first semi-colon in `'".$password."';";` as in `'".$password."' ";` for `login.php`

Comment: @Fred-ii- semi colons in MySQL are optional for one query, required for multiple, but will not affect the result in this case.

Comment: I thought the semi-colon was a termination character @scrowler

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is. Much like any other language, you terminate the end of the line with it. Having it there or not on a single query won't make any difference, much like Javascript and most other languages.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my previous comment about `if ($num_rows <= 0)` what I use to check if a record exists is in fact `if ($num_rows > 0)` so you may want to use that instead. That may be "one" of the problems you're having.

Comment: thank you guys for all the answers! I already made some changes to the php code, but what I think is happening is that the $_SESSION['username'] is not carrying over to my input page code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `INSERT` SQL contains a PHP `array` variable which should be expressed like:

```
VALUES (
    '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "', '$value2', '$value3',
    '$value4', '$value5', '$value6', '$value7', '$value8'
)
```

or

```
VALUES (
    '{$_SESSION['username']}', '$value2', '$value3',
    '$value4', '$value5', '$value6', '$value7', '$value8'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape your quotes for that variable:

```
VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['username'] . "',
```